# C++ Template Specialization with non-generic arguments

Tags: c++, templates, generics

i have a quiestion regarding template specializations when i have multiple arguments and some of them are non generic

I have a class called Polinom(polynomian) which is basically an array of T objects with a size declared in the template definition(as an int). I also have a class called Complex. Now what I want is to create a template specialization so that I will call different functions(overloaded operator functions) when I have a polinomial with Complex as T. My question is how can I do this, I am getting an error "type name not allowed, stepen undefined" when trying to create the specialization, if someone could clear up what is going on here that would be great.

```
  #pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

template<class T, int stepen>
class Polinom
{
private:
    T koeficijenti[stepen];
public:
    Polinom() {};
    ~Polinom() {};
    void ucitajKoef();
    T vrednost(T x);
};

template<>
class Polinom<Complex, int stepen> //error type name not allowed
{

};

template<class T, int stepen>
T Polinom<T, stepen>::vrednost(T x)
{
    T suma = koeficijenti[1] * (T)pow(x, stepen);
    for (int i = 1; i < stepen; i++)
    {
        suma += koeficijenti[i] * pow(x, stepen - i);
    }
    return suma;
}

template<class T, int stepen>
void Polinom<T, stepen>::ucitajKoef()
{
    T uneseniKoef;
    for (int i = 0; i < stepen; i++)
    {
        cout << "Unesite koeficijent" << endl;
        cin >> uneseniKoef;
        koeficijenti[i] = uneseniKoef;
    }
}
```

P.S. Is there a workaround to having to rewrite all the other functions of the class since I am only specializing so I can overload the function vrednost(value)

Comment: Your code isn't readable because of variable names.

Comment: Did you mean `template<int stepen> class Polinom<Complex, stepen>`? In the future, please read on how to produce a [MCVE]. Most of the code here isn't necessary and distracts from the problem.

Comment: Well, that seemed to have fixed the proble, but...why?

Comment: Because that's the syntax for partial specialization.

Answer (score 0):

The specialization should look like:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, int N>
struct Array {
    T var[N];
    T sum() { 
        T res{};
        for (T v:var) {
            res += v;
        }
        return res;
    }
};

struct Complex {};

template <int N>
struct Array<Complex, N> {
    Complex var[N];
    Complex sum() {
        std::cout <<"Complex sum called\n";
        return {};
    }
};


int main()
{
    Array<Complex,5> array;
    array.sum();
}
```

Note that this is a minimal (I think), complete, and verifiable example.  You will get better answers if you take the time to create something similar when you ask a question.

To answer your question: I know of no way to simply specialize just one function in a template - which is why you get complex things like the CRTP and individual functions which are invoked from the members (and which can be individually specialized).